# Function to split a file to table

Tags: r

frame that looks like this:

> ```
> Col1       Col2
> Name1      Attr1=10;Attr2=24; Attr3=5;Attr4=9;    
> Name2      Attr1=1;Attr3=2.4; Attr4=16;Attr5=90;          
> Name3      Attr1=2;Attr2=45; Attr4=122;Attr6=120;
> ```

I would like the following output:

> ```
> Col1      Attr1    Attr2   Attr3   Attr4   Attr5   Attr6   
> Name1       10       24       5      9       NA      NA     
> Name2       1        NA      2.4     16      90      NA     
> Name3       2        45      NA      122     NA      120
> ```

What can I try next?

Comment: I think the question was downvoted because you did not show any effort on your side to resolve it. Please try to include what you have tried even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I understand. The problem is that I don't know how to start..but anyway, thank you a lot!

Comment: How did your data get in this form to begin with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but it is too long. I am pretty sure that there is simpler method.

```
dat <- read.table(text='Col1       Col2
Name1      Attr1=10;Attr2=24; Attr3=5;Attr4=9;    
Name2      Attr1=1;Attr3=2.4; Attr4=16;Attr5=90;          
Name3      Attr1=2;Attr2=45; Attr4=122;Attr6=120;',
                  header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

res <- do.call(cbind,lapply(dat,function(x)
      do.call(rbind,strsplit(x,split=";"))))

indx <- gsub('Attr([0-9]+).*','\\1',res)
vals <- gsub('.*=([0-9]+)','\\1',res)

mm <- max(as.integer(indx))
M <- matrix(NA_real_,nrow=nrow(res),ncol=mm)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(M)))
  M[i,as.integer(indx[i,])] <- as.numeric(vals[i,])

rownames(M) <- rownames(dat)
colnames(M) <- paste0('Attr',seq_len(mm))


     Attr1 Attr2 Attr3 Attr4 Attr5 Attr6
Name1    10    24   5.0     9    NA    NA
Name2     1    NA   2.4    16    90    NA
Name3     2    45    NA   122    NA   120
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `dat` from @agstudy's answer above, you can try using my "splitstackshape" package along with the "reshape2" package as follows:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(reshape2)

## Convert the rownames to an "ID" column
dat$ID <- rownames(dat)

## Split Col1 and Col2 into a "lonf" form
S1 <- concat.split.multiple(dat, c("Col1", "Col2"), ";", "long")

## Make that output even longer
S2 <- melt(S1[complete.cases(S1), ], id.vars=c("ID", "time"))

## Split again, this time on the "="
S3 <- concat.split.multiple(S2, "value", "=")

## Use `dcast` to get the data into the right shape
dcast(S3, ID ~ value_1, value.var="value_2")
#      ID Attr1 Attr2 Attr3 Attr4 Attr5 Attr6
# 1 Name1    10    24   5.0     9    NA    NA
# 2 Name2     1    NA   2.4    16    90    NA
# 3 Name3     2    45    NA   122    NA   120
```

Comment: +1! excellent! you convince me to test `splitstackshape package`

Comment: @agstudy, still a lot of work to be done, so let me know if you have any ideas.